# How to specify ssh custom port in GitKraken on Windows?

Tags: windows, ssh, gitlab, gitkraken

I'm running a Gitkraken client on Windows 10. I've a remote GitLab (self-hosted) server listening SSH on port 2222. It seems, i can't use an SSH, whatever i tried to :

> ```
> Clone Failed
> Configured SSH key is invalid.
> Please confirm that it is properly associated with your Git provider.
> ```

After some digging, it seems Gitkraken doesn't read my ssh config file witch specify my custom ssh port (Sourcetree works just fine).

**How do I specify my ssh custom port in GitKraken ?**

Comment: This depend on the service, we had once used BitBucket server which used custom port so all the clone links had `ssh://dmain:port/repo` structure. Check the documentation of the service you're using.

Comment: I'm not sur to understand what kind of service you are referring to. I already tried to use the "GitLab self-hosted" service connector in Gitkraken, i got the same error when i tried to clone/push/pull anything from the repo.

Comment: You need to configure the GitLab to allow SSH on a certain port and GitLab should present you with clone link that has port specified. If you're looking for free private repository solution, why not use Bitbucket from Atlassian? You don't have to worry about overhead of maintaining the server either and loss of data.